# Why my Mapfragment only run like launch activity and not inside on another activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, maps, fragment

I´m having problems with my app and I have not idea why.
I have an app with two java class (MapActivity,which it is a fragment map and ActivityMain) and also I have two XML files. Activity_main.xml and Activity_maps.xml.

My problem is the next:
If I change the manifest to launch MapActivity, all works fine.
[Example of my MapsActivity working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anQhx.png)

But if I change the manifest launch to ActivityMain, the Mapfragment don´t work.
[MapsActivity don´t work.The map cant create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I8P0.png)

This is the code of the ActivityMain

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

and this is the code of activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="14"
tools:context="com.pjcdev.ceassalamanca.MainActivity">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    map:cameraZoom="14"
    tools:context="com.pjcdev.ceassalamanca.MapsActivity"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showmsg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="12"
    android:text="El lugar buscado pertenece a la zona de
   CEAS GARRIDO NORTE"
    android:textColor="#2E2EFE"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="457dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

and this is the code of the mapsactivity.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:cameraZoom="14"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.pjcdev.ceassalamanca.MapsActivity" />
```

Anybody can help me? I suspect that the problem is on activity_main.xml but I don´t know...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I change the manifest to MapsActivity to launch
and I copy the code of the Activity_main.xml and paste on Maps_activity.xml
Now, run without problems.

I can delete ActivityMain java class and xml file

I don´t know the reason why didn´t work...but work! hahaha

thanks!